# Meaning of ${project.basedir} in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

What is the meaning of

```
<directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
```

and

```
${project.build.directory}
```

in pom.xml

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Build_Settings

Comment: Hardly off-topic, reason given for closing seems wholly inappropriate.

Comment: @EdRandall reason for closing is invalid indeed, however I'm not sure, that there is a point for reopening, answers are already given. This may be worth to setting as protected, instead of closed

Answer (score 84):

There are a set of available properties to all Maven projects.

From [Introduction to the POM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Available_Variables):

> `project.basedir`: The directory that the current project resides in.

This means this points to where your Maven projects resides on your system. It corresponds to the location of the `pom.xml` file. If your POM is located inside `/path/to/project/pom.xml` then this property will evaluate to `/path/to/project`.

Some properties are also inherited from the [Super POM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Super_POM), which is the case for `project.build.directory`. It is the value inside the `<project><build><directory>` element of the POM. You can get a description of all those values by looking at the [Maven model](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-model/maven.html#class_build). For `project.build.directory`, it is:

> The directory where all files generated by the build are placed. The default value is `target`.

This is the directory that will hold every generated file by the build.

Comment: Is there any maven variable to reference resources of a module A from module B under a Parent P ?

Answer (score 29):

`${project.basedir}` is the root directory of your project.

`${project.build.directory}` is equivalent to `${project.basedir}/target`

as it is defined here: 
https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/trunk/maven-model-builder/src/main/resources/org/apache/maven/model/pom-4.0.0.xml#L53

Comment: Not necessarily the "root directory" if your `pom.xml` is in a subdirectory, as the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35985280/4179032) explains